# IonIcons in NPM & Webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, ionicons

Can anyone give me an example of how to use [ion-icons](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons) in webpack using imports?

I've been struggling for a while with things like:

```
import 'ionicons/dist/ionicons.js';
...
<ion-icon name='add' />
```

And nothing seems to be working, even after looking at the cryptic source code inside the npm package.

Please help?

P.s.: please don't suggest including the external script, an npm package should be usable via imports, and not:
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.0.0/dist/ionicons.js"></script>`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can import most of the icons as svgs:

```
import {logoTwitter} from "ionicons/icons";
var q = document.querySelector("#blankdiv")
q.innerHTML = `<a href="">${logoTwitter.slice(s.indexOf('<'))}</a>`
```

Unfortunately, this seems to not work with some, such as `refresh`.